# (bsValueChange) not working after adding dateCustomClasses

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datepicker

After adding dateCustomClasses, bsValueChange function is not working.. Pls help

HTML

```
<bs-datepicker-inline [bsValue]="list" 
          [bsConfig]="{
            dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            selectFromOtherMonth: false,
            showWeekNumbers: false,
            defaultViewDate : false
          }"
          [dateCustomClasses]="dateCustomClasses" (bsValueChange)="handleChangePicker($event)"
          >
        </bs-datepicker-inline>
```

TS

```
this.dateCustomClasses = [
      { date: new Date('10-17-2019'), classes: ['icon-paid'] },       
      { date: new Date('10-18-2019'), classes: ['icon-arrange'] },
      { date: new Date('10-19-2019'), classes: ['icon-missed'] },
];
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: no... no error.. just click not working.. if [dateCustomClasses]="dateCustomClasses" removed its working fine. But I want custom icons in my calender

Comment: Same issue with me. I also set dateCustomClass property dynamically but bsValueChange event stops working. No idea what is the issue @VishnuShenoy

Comment: any solution for this? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
 <bs-datepicker-inline 
 ***ngIf='dataSet.length > 0 && dateCustomClasses && datesDisabled'**

placeholder="Datepicker" [bsConfig]="{showWeekNumbers:false}"
              bsDatepicker (bsValueChange)="updateMyDate($event)" [dateCustomClasses]="dateCustomClasses"
              [datesDisabled]="datesDisabled">
            </bs-datepicker-inline>
```

Initially, we have to check for data. So add the If condition to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After created `dateCustomClasses`, re-render your Calendar.
Here is my way:

- Init value that hide your calendar (ex: `showCalendar = false`), use showCalendar as display condition in your HTML.
- After created `dateCustomClasses`, set `showCalendar = true`.